# Ensuring SSIS package on server and source control match

Tags: version-control, ssis

Does anyone have any tips to ensure the SSIS on a production server is in sync with source control?

The only way I can think of to do that is have a separate group that always deploys the SSIS packages, but that isn't feasible in my environment.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can check the version number of the package in source control and the version number on the server.

You can also export the package on the server to the file system of your development box and check to see if the .dtsx file is the same as the one you have in source control.

Answer (score 0):

You could also compare/diff XMLs...